# Javascript- why is my JQuery AJAX request failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to JQuery and I really am not sure why this get and post request isn't working.  I keep getting the error message.  I'd appreciate any advice or resources to help figure this out.  Thanks in advance.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://api.github.com/users/noeladd", function(json){$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://httpbin.org/post",
  data: json,
  success: function(){ 
    var parentDiv = document.getElementByClassName('container')[0];
    var div = "<div><img src = 'json.avatar_url' width = '150px'></img><br> json.login <br> json.name</div>";
    parentDiv.append(div);
  } ,
  error: function(){
    alert("request failed!")
  },
  dataType: JSON
});});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get it... but take it corrected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sample</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
  <script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.github.com/users/noeladd", function(json){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://httpbin.org/post",
        data: json,
        success: function(data){
          //You not using data... why???  
          var parentDiv = $('.container');
          var div = "<div><img src = '"+json.avatar_url+"' width = '150px'></img><br> "+json.login+" <br> "+json.name+"</div>";
          parentDiv.append(div);

        } ,
        error: function(){
          alert("request failed!")
        },
        dataType: 'json'
      });});
    })
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This definitely helped me to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you post the json to another website that only return the dada posted, but take a look at this example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/noeladd", function (json) {

        $("<div />").append(
            $("<img />").attr("src", json.avatar_url).css("width", 150),
            $("<br />"),
            $("<span />").text(json.login),
            $("<br />"),
            $("<span />").text(json.name)
        ).appendTo("div.container:eq(0)");

    });

});
```

Working example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evandroprogram/Lbqbewsz/

Comment: I was doing it that way because that's how the instructions of the problem asked me to do it.  The answer Meola gave me above helped me to figure out what I did wrong.